# Getting something wrong while building parse table for the grammar

Tags: compilers, parsers

**Task**
Build the Parse Table

> Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the following context-free grammar:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> E &\to TE' \\ E' &\to +TE'\; |\; \epsilon \\ T &\to F T' \; \\
> T' &\to *FT'|\;\;\epsilon \\F &\to (E)\; | \;id \\ 
> \end{aligned}
> $$

I calculated $ FIRST $ and $ FOLLOW $ sets
\begin{aligned}
FIRST(F) = FIRST(T) = FIRST(E) = \{ (,id \} \\ FIRST(T') = \{*,\epsilon\}\\
FIRST(E') = \{+,\epsilon\} \\FOLLOW(E) = FOLLOW(E') = \{ ),$ \} \\ FOLLOW(T)=FOLLOW(T') = \{+,),$\}\\
FOLLOW(F) = \{ +, * ,$ , )\}
\end{aligned}

Here is the rule while constructing parse table\
$$For\; each\; terminal\; a\; in\; FIRST(A)\;,\; add \; A \to \alpha; to\; M[A,a]$$

When applying this rule to the production $$F\to(E)$$ I need to add this to $M[F,id]$ and $M[F,(]$ so when applying this rule again to $F\to id$, Should I need to add again to $M[F,id]$? Then ; It; is not LL(1) ]; grammar right? But it is given LL(1) . How , any mistake I have done?

Comment: It's a long time ago, but I thought F -> (E) together with the rule that F is reachable means E can be followed by ).

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for pointing it out I've edited it, I made an error while typing!

Answer (score 0):

You have missed one important note. The rule is such

> For each production $A→α$ of the grammar, do the following:
> For each terminal $a$ in $FIRST(A)$, add $A→α;$ to $M[A,a]$

that is we only consider the elements in first set which is contributed by the production $A→α$ which here is $F→(E)$ ,

so for this rule ie $F→(E)$ the $FIRST(F) = \{(\}$ only

and for $F→id$ , $FIRST(F) = \{id\}$